# Docker Windows Network Routing

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-network

I have a Windows Docker host where I want to have containers for multiple environments.

**How can I route web traffic coming to the host to specific containers based on URL+Port?**

I know how to do this based on port but I also need routing based on URL.

For example:
I will have 2 environments; QA and Dev, each with its own URL, but on the same port.

NGINX is not an option because I am on Windows Docker.

I thought of installing IIS ARR on the host, but Docker does not really fit the scenario of web farm (or maybe I can use it somehow?)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple actually. Go ahead and run an Nginx *container* (then it makes no difference that your Docker Desktop is on Windows):

https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt/

From there, just adjust your Nginx proxies to listen to the URL's/paths/ports you want per container, and it'll route the traffic wherever you want it to go.

The container I linked is very popular, and very easy to learn and use. They do most of the work for you already, so the learning curve is pretty small.

Comment: I'm afraid NGINX is not an option. Docker on windows cannot run Linux containers:
"latest: Pulling from linuxserver/letsencrypt
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries"

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/running-docker-windows-and-linux-containers-simultaneously/